# Update the column if the value >= input quantity

Tags: mysql

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=177d33c265e216e6f1b1ce1e381d7484

From the above query in the dbfiddle I'm marking all the rows approval_status to 1 if the input quantity is greater than the column value.

In the above example, third row with part_id `17` won't update as the total 30+50+60=140 is greater than 90.In this case, I want to save the remaining quantity ie. 10 (90 - (30+50)) and **next time when the query is performing I want to add the next input quantity value with 10 and continue the execution**. I've created a new table(`part_ids`) in the dbfiddle to mark the remaining quantity. I've achieved the sum checking and updating the approval_status field, but stuck in saving the remaining qty and continuing execution.

You are welcome to suggest if any other better approach also.

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: Can you add the examples to the question? It makes the question easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare variable to store remaining quantities.

   SET @rem_qty :=0;

> Fetch and Assign the value from your part_ids table in future

I hope this query can help you find the remaining quantities

```
SELECT @rem_qty := qty_pending 
FROM (SELECT SUM(qty_req) OVER (ORDER BY reg_date) cum_sum,
             @qty-SUM(qty_req) OVER (ORDER BY reg_date) as qty_pending 
      FROM test 
      WHERE part_id = @part_id        )a
WHERE qty_pending>=0 
ORDER BY qty_pending limit 1;
```

Sub query will give the below result:

| cum_sum | qty_pending |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 60 |
| 80 | 10 |
| 140 | -50 |

We need to fetch the least value of pending quantity before becoming less than zero. so we are using `where qty_pending>=0 order by qty_pending limit 1` and assigning it to @rem_qty.

Use this @rem_qty to insert/update the remaining quantity values the part_ids table.

I recommend you to use `UPSERT` logic in your part_ids table instead of plain insert because it may create duplicates during the second load with same part_id.